# Using onclick="alert('')" to confirm answer

Tags: html, forms, onclick, xhtml, alert

I am writing an XHTML form, and I need a little help. I have used a button to allow the user to reset.
When the alert triggers, I want it to give them the option to proceed or cancel, but all I am getting is an 'Ok' which will run the reset anyway.
Any help is greatly appreciated, as I am new to HTML. 
Thanks.

Edit: I am now using confirm, but either button click in the confirm box are proceeding with the reset of the form anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks, I have changed it, but if I enter information into the form, click reset and then click cancel on the confirm box, it resets the form anyway... Any ideas? The button is type 'reset'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `confirm`, not `alert`.

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Really send form?');">
    ...
</form>
```

I used `submit` event on form instead of `onclick` event on `button`, because you can send form using `enter` too, not just by `button`.